# Spark Structured Streaming: read first N messages in a kafka topic as a batch query

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a requirement where i want to sample a kafka topic(for checking its data quality, etc) before triggering a streaming job onto it. One of the parameter to sampling could be number of messages.

I am referencing "http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries" but only found these methods, "startingOffsets" and "endingOffsets". It won't be possible to read first N messages from it as offsets need not be continous (in case of compaction or deletion of messages).

Looking for any suggestion or help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing your post you don't need to build a streaming application. You want to create a batch job which will perform data quality control.

`KafkaUtils.createRDD` method can help to passing offset ranges which you want to extract from Kafka. It takes array of offsetRanges for each Kafka partition. With help of these method it is possible to configure the number of messages you want to extract from Kafka topic.

Below code will read 10 messages from Kafka topic (5 messages from each partition):

```
val offsetRanges = Array(
  // topic, partition, inclusive starting offset, exclusive ending offset
  OffsetRange("topic_name", 0, 0, 5),
  OffsetRange("topic_name", 1, 0, 5)
)

val rdd = KafkaUtils.createRDD[String, String](sparkContext, kafkaParams, offsetRanges, PreferConsistent)
```

Note: Kafka TTL will delete messages from the topic so you need to set offsets carefully other-ways you application will try to fetch unexisting messages. Ideally is to use [beginningOffsets](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/Consumer.html#beginningOffsets(java.util.Collection)) method from Kafka consumer interface.

You can find more in Spark documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#creating-an-rdd

Comment: Thanks Alex. Last part of your answer is exactly my problem. As offsets might change due to compaction or deletion, i can't be 100% sure on starting and ending offsets to read.

Comment: You can use `beginningOffsets` in order to get first available message in Kafka and `endOffsets` in order to get last available message in Kafka (under available I mean that message is still in Kafka).